# MySQL: creating a column that consists of values from three other columns in different table

Tags: mysql

I would like to know if it is possible to create a table with a column that references values from three other columns. Example is below:

```
CREATE TABLE Students
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    Student_Name VARCHAR(25), 
    Course_Name VARCHAR(25), 
    First_Mark VARCHAR(25), 
    Second_Mark VARCHAR(25), 
    Third_Mark VARCHAR(25)
);
CREATE TABLE Course
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Student_Course_Name VARCHAR(25),
    First_Subject VARCHAR(25), <------|*************************************************
    Second_Subject VARCHAR(25), <-----| I want to connect values from these columns... *
    Third_Subject VARCHAR(25), <------|*************************************************
    FOREIGN KEY (Students_Course_Name) references Students (Course_Name)
);

CREATE TABLE Timetable
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    Subject_List VARCHAR(25), <-------| *** ...with this column. In other words, I want mentioned columns to be related.
    Date DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, 
    Avarage_Mark INTEGER,
);
```

Here is what I want:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB0AV.png

Edit 2: Full script. Purpose of this exercise is to create a database that contains students, subjects, and exam timetable.

Comment: What do you mean by related?  Do you want them to be the same?

Comment: I will add one more example in a minute to better explain what I want to achieve.

Comment: Does the Timetable refer to the course schedule, or does it map a student's personal schedule ?

Comment: Timetable will contain exam date and time and corresponding subject, which will be one of those that are included in Course table, First_Subject, Second_Subject, Third_Subject. This is how I wanted it to be initially. But if you have an idea of a different design please advise.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker, but if Timetable is going to hold exam results, then you should probably rename it :-) If the student can pass an exam without discussing all of that exam subjects, then I think you should have a TimetableSubject table that would keep track of what subjects the exam was about. (See @explosion-pill's answer too.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not good relational DB practice to have numbered columns like "First_Subject," etc. unless you can guarantee that the rows will only ever have that many subjects, but no more (and perhaps no less).  Even then, I would be hesitant.

Instead you could have a `Subject` table with subjects and then a `Subject-Courses` table that linked courses to as many or few subjects as you like.  You could then also have Timetable rows that link to `Subject` rows.

An example schema (I'm sure you can figure out the DDL) given your question would be:

```
Students (stuID, name)
StudentCourses (scID, couID, stuID, enrollmentDate)
StudentCourseMarks (scID, mark, markDate)
Courses (couID, name)
Subjects (subID, subject)
CourseSubjects (couID, subID)
```

I'm not really sure how `Timetable` would fit in.  Seems to be more of a derived table, i.e. it should not exist as part of the schema.

Comment: Could you possibly include a simplest working example of a code? To get a better understanding of what you propose.

Comment: I have edited my question. It now includes full script with some explanation.

Comment: Why course name ? Why not a StudentCourse table (many-to-many relation between courses and students ?)

Comment: Basically, @ExplosionPills is encouraging OP to normalize the database correctly. Each student course should be assigned a unique ID, which is then referenced to/from the Subject table (each entry in the Subject table will be linked to the appropriate student courses).

Comment: @ExplosionPills After reading your advice I have tried to redesign my tables. Would it be a good practice to include subject names and corresponding course and to repeat course name where appropriate?

Comment: @doc The point of normalizing the database is to avoid redundant row information...

Comment: @ExplosionPills, maybe the Timetable table should be named Mark, and should be in 1-to-n relationship with Student (thus avoiding those First_Mark, etc. columns). Or, exam date and mark could be additional columns of the student-course relationship...